# how to set custom Array object to soapObject.addProperty in Ksoap2

Tags: java, android

how to set custom Array  object to soapObject.addProperty in Ksoap2?
 I used Ksoap2 and i want send message to soap api.

> the soap structure api send message is:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://ICAN.ir/Farzin/WebServices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:SendMessage>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:Subject>?</web:Subject>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:Content>?</web:Content>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:messagefile>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <web:MessageFile>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:FileName>?</web:FileName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:FileBinary>cid:1212299696454</web:FileBinary>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:FileExtension>?</web:FileExtension>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:Description>?</web:Description>
            </web:MessageFile>
         </web:messagefile>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:receiver>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <web:Receiver>
               <web:RoleID>?</web:RoleID>
               <web:UserID>?</web:UserID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:UserName>?</web:UserName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <web:NativeID>?</web:NativeID>
            </web:Receiver>
         </web:receiver>
      </web:SendMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**for example i want send messagefile array object what can i do?**

> this is my MessageFile object:

```
    public class MessageFile implements KvmSerializable {

    String FileName;
    String FileBinary;
    String FileExtension;

    public String getFileName() {
        return FileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileBinary() {
        return FileBinary;
    }

    public void setFileBinary(String fileBinary) {
        FileBinary = fileBinary;
    }

    public String getFileExtension() {
        return FileExtension;
    }

    public void setFileExtension(String fileExtension) {
        FileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public MessageFile() {
    }

    public MessageFile(String fileName, String fileBinary, String fileExtension) {
        FileName = fileName;
        FileBinary = fileBinary;
        FileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return FileName;
            case 1:
                return FileBinary;

            case 2:
                return FileExtension;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                propertyInfo.name = "FileName";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                propertyInfo.name = "FileBinary";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 2:
                propertyInfo.name = "FileExtension";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                this.FileName = value.toString();
                break;
            case 1:
                this.FileBinary = value.toString();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.FileExtension = value.toString();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

i know how to send object. but i dont know how to send array
 object.please help me what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem solution from this site:
[How to send a Complext type Array](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ksoap2-android/-OF73sxrZdc)

```
SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NameSpace, MetodeName);
        soapObject.addProperty("Subject", objSubject);
        soapObject.addProperty("Content", objContent);

        SoapObject messageFileHeader = new SoapObject(NameSpace,"messagefile");

        for (int i = 0; i < structureAttaches.size(); i++) {
            MessageFile messageFile = new MessageFile(structureAttaches.get(i).getName(), structureAttaches.get(i).getBase64File(), structureAttaches.get(i).getFileExtension());
            messageFileHeader.addProperty("MessageFile", messageFile);
        }

        SoapObject receiverHeader = new SoapObject(NameSpace,"receiver");

        for (int i = 0; i < structureUserAndRole.size(); i++) {
            Receiver receiver = new Receiver(structureUserAndRole.get(i).getRole_ID(),structureUserAndRole.get(i).getUser_ID());
            receiverHeader.addProperty("Receiver", receiver);
        }

        soapObject.addSoapObject(messageFileHeader);
        soapObject.addSoapObject(receiverHeader);
```